# Invalid Syntax from except

Tags: python

I am receiving an invalid syntax from the line that says except: from this code...

```
from .utils.dataIO import fileIO
from .utils import checks
from __main__ import send_cmd_help
from __main__ import settings as bot_settings
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json
import os

class Transformice:
    """Transformice"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @checks.is_owner()
    @commands.group(name="tfm", pass_context=True, invoke_without_command=True)
    async def tfm(self, ctx):
        """Get Transformice Stats"""
        await send_cmd_help(ctx)

    @checks.is_owner()
    @tfm.command(pass_context=True)
    async def mouse(self, ctx, *name):
        """Get mouse info"""

        if name == ():
            mouse = "+".join(name)
            link = "http://api.micetigri.fr/json/player/" + mouse
            async with aiohttp.get(link) as r:
                result = await r.json()
                name = result['name']
                msg = "**Mouse:** {}".format(name)
                await self.bot.say(msg)
        except:
                await self.bot.say("Invalid username!")

def setup(bot):    
    n = Transformice(bot)
    bot.add_cog(n)
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it. I am confuse about some errors in python and how to fix that.

Comment: Where in the documentation have you found `if/except` construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `except` clause only makes sense after a `try` block, and there isn't one. It seems you're not looking for exception handling but simply an `else` clause.

Either

```
try:
    code_that_might_fail()
except ValueError:
    print("ouch.")
```

or

```
if condition:
    do_this()
else:
    do_that()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put a

`try-except` block together but in your code. 
You have used only the `except block`... No `try` statement.

```
   try:
        if name == ():
            mouse = "+".join(name)
            link = "http://api.micetigri.fr/json/player/" + mouse
            async with aiohttp.get(link) as r:
                result = await r.json()
                name = result['name']
                msg = "**Mouse:** {}".format(name)
                await self.bot.say(msg)
    except:
            await self.bot.say("Invalid username!")
```

you should use something like above if the error is only because of the `except` syntax.
or there could be you wish to use `else:` and have used `except`